# How to mock/spyOn a call to a function from a different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have this function, that gets called on submit. When the payload has been posted, I want to call a function in a separate file called `showResponseMessage`:

Contact.js

```
import { onValueChangeHandler, showResponseMessage, extractData } from '../../utility/Helpers/Helpers';


const [config, setConfig] = useState(initialState)

const recommendationHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.post('/contact.json', extractData(config.addMessage))
            .then(() => {
                showResponseMessage(`Din besked er sendt.`, initialState, false, setConfig, 5000);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                showResponseMessage(`Der opstod en fejl ved sendning. Prøv igen senere.`, {}, true, setConfig, 10000);
            });
    }
```

The problem arises when I am trying to do spyOn on the function as follows:

Contact.test.js

```
it.only('should POST data to server if necessary payload is included', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Contact />);
        jest.spyOn(helpers, 'showResponseMessage')
        jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockResolvedValueOnce({
            data: [
                {
                    userId: 1,
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'test'
                }
            ]
        });

        wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', {
            preventDefault: () => { }
        });
        expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(helpers.showResponseMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Helpers.js

```
export const showResponseMessage = (message, initialState, error, callback, time) => {
    if (!error) {
        callback({...initialState, responseMessage: message, error: error });
        setTimeout(() => {
            callback({...initialState, responseMessage: '', error: error });
        }, time)
    } else {
        callback(prevState => ({...prevState, responseMessage: message, error: error }));
        setTimeout(() => {
            callback(prevState => ({...prevState, responseMessage: '', error: error }));
        }, time)
    }

}
```

It returns 0 called times.
I am not too sure how to spyOn a function call from a separate file.

I suppose I could test if the UI updated, but I am not sure how to move the lifecycle forward while test (in Jasmine, I remember when I made an async call, I would have to forcibly make the lifecycle progress to make sure the changes had happened). The `showResponseMessage` also should also trigger state update, as I pass the updateConfig to be used triggered by that specific function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
jest.mock('../path/to/Helpers', () => ({
  __esModule: true, // this property makes it work
  showResponseMessage: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Comment: Maybe I should've shown that, but in order to `expect(helpers.showResponseMessage)`, I import it in the top as: `import * as helpers from '../path/to/helpers.js'`. With your solution, it tells me either: if I remove the import, that showREsponseMessage doesn't exist, or if I keep it, that expects expect a mock for spy function.

Comment: I am also starting to think, that my async axios call does not resolve and reach the call back in time. I am afraid it just bypasses it, causing the showResponseMessage never to be called.